# SELECT past hour data

Tags: postgresql, select, time

I have a simple database

```
id    name      value    date          time
1     box       34       2020-06-08    14:45:00
2     box       35       2020-06-08    15:00:00
3     box       4        2020-06-08    15:15:00
4     box       44       2020-06-08    15:30:00
5     box       42       2020-06-08    15:45:00
6     box       41       2020-06-08    16:00:00
7     box       0        2020-06-08    16:15:00
8     box       0        2020-06-08    16:30:00
9     box       0        2020-06-08    16:45:00
...
```

I am trying to retrieve the **latest past 1 hour** data from a Postgresql database. The objective is to run this query every hour to get the past one hour data for further processing in another software.

The records in the database already contain all the timestamps for the day (15 minutes interval).

Therefore, from the example, assuming my local time is 16:00:00, I will want to take the past 1 hour data from my local time.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT id, name, value, date, time
FROM boxbox 
WHERE time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour') 
ORDER BY time desc
```

But I am getting this SQL error

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: time without time zone >= 
timestamp with time zone
```

The table datatype is as follow:

```
id - int4
name - varchar
value - int
date - date
time - time
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use two columns instead of just one `timestamp` column?

Comment: Did you try this - `WHERE itime >= (NOW()::time - INTERVAL '1 hour') `?

Comment: @VivekS. I have just updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `now()` returns a `timestamp with time zone`, not a `time` value. And you can't compare a `time` value with a `timestamp with time zone` value.

You need to use [`localtime`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
SELECT id, name, value, "date", "time"
FROM boxbox 
WHERE "time" >= localtime - INTERVAL '1 hour'
ORDER BY "time" desc
```

However the above won't work properly if the time crossed midnight. If you also need to take care of that, you need to combine your `date` and `time` columns to a single `timestamp` column:

```
SELECT id, name, value, "date", "time"
FROM boxbox 
WHERE "date" + "time" >= now () - INTERVAL '1 hour'
ORDER BY "time" desc
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried your query, it did not filter properly. For example, my local time is now 3 PM, when I run the query, it filter and gave the data from 3PM to midnight. I have used your second block of code to test in my dataset. I will modify my question. Please wait.

Comment: Figured out how to make it work for my case now. Marking this as answer, thanks.